# ipython pandas crosstab margins error

Tags: python, ipython, typeerror, crosstab

I'm trying to do a crosstab frequency table with subtotals (margins), but I keep getting the error

```
In: pandas.crosstab(xyz.row_variable,xyz.column_variable,margins=True)
Out:
...
TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex
```

I don't get this error when I delete the `margins=True` option

```
In: pandas.crosstab(xyz.row_variable,xyz.column_variable)
Out:
column_variable A       B       C
row_variable            
low             1506    3472    20817
high            356     703     3325
```

I've tried creating categorical array variables for each column in the DataFrame that I am using and passing those to crosstab, but that didn't help.

Any thoughts as to why this error is popping up and what I can do about it?